# Angular/Typescript Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular

Trying to call an api and retrieve data from it however it is throwing this error.

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

my service looks like

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../Models/user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  apiUrl = 'myurl is in here but i cannot show'

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(){
    return this._http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

user model looks like

```
export class User {
    alertId: any;
    itemId: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    categoryId: any;
    riskId: any;
    sourceId: any;
    startDate: any;
    endDate: any;
    link: string;
    countryId: any;
    countries: string;
    keywordMatches: string;
    keywordsMatched: 0;
    createdDate: any;
    createdBy: any;
    isDeleted: true;
    deletedDate: any;
    deletedBy: any;
    latitude: 0;
    longitude: 0;
    notes: string;
    customerId: any;
    formattedAddress: any;
    firstname: any;
    surname: any;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    smsEnabled: true;
    customerName: string;
    homeCountryId: any;
    travellerTagId: 0;
}
```

This t.s component using it

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/Models/user.model';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/Services/data.service';
 
 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav-alerts',
  templateUrl: './side-nav-alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav-alerts.component.css']
})
export class SideNavAlertsComponent implements OnInit {
users$: User[];
  constructor( private dataService : DataService) { }



  ngOnInit(){
    return this.dataService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(data => this.users$ = data)
  
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor = 'let user of users$' style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
    </div>
```

any ideas on how I could use this to loop over ?
I essentially just wanna loop over it and display the info collected from the api I understand that maybe I need to convert this into another data type but I am unsure on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.users$ = this.dataService.getUsers()  
}
```

instead of

```
ngOnInit(){
  return this.dataService.getUsers()
  .subscribe(data => this.users$ = data)
}
```

Since data is actual data and not a `Subscription` resp. `Observable`.
And btw there's no reason for your `ngOnInit` to have a return statement.

Turn

```
users$: User[];
```

into

```
users$: Observable<User[]>;
```

Inside your html you need to use the async pipe like so:

```
*ngFor = 'let user of (users$ | async)' style="text-align: center;"
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! but i still get this error. ``` Type 'Observable<User[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': json, length, pop, push, and 26 more.ts(2740)```

Comment: that means that you dont have an Observable of an array but something else. Btw: your User class does not have a member named name. A stackblitz would be nice.

Comment: how would i make it as an observable? Sorry I have never used stackblitz before

Comment: users$: User[]; -> users$: Observable<User[]>;

Comment: core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. still throwing

Comment: Have you looked at the response in your browsers dev-tools? Is it successful? Is 'data'    really an array of Users?

Comment: This answer should work. Its is probably the response that is not an array as stated by @acincognito

Comment: Have sett this as answer as this work thankyou for your help!!